How to Modify a Pydantic nested Model to Return a Specific Field Instead of an Object
I am working with Pydantic models in FastAPI. I have a UserDTO model that inherits from a base model (InternalEntity). The UserDTO model includes a relationship with a company object, but in the data transfer object (DTO), I only want to return the company_name rather than the entire company object.
Here is the current implementation:
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel
from datetime import date

class UserDTO(InternalEntity):
    keycloak_user_id: str
    first_name: str
    last_name: str
    gender: str
    email: str
    role: UserRole
    phone_number: str
    birthdate: Optional[date] = None
    address: Optional[_AddressBase] = None
    job: Optional[_JobBase] = None
    company: _CompanyBase
    isactive: bool

I want to modify the model so that it only returns company_name instead of the entire company object. The modified model should look like this:
class UserDTO(InternalEntity):
    keycloak_user_id: str
    first_name: str
    last_name: str
    gender: str
    email: str
    role: UserRole
    phone_number: str
    birthdate: Optional[date] = None
    address: Optional[_AddressBase] = None
    job: Optional[_JobBase] = None
    company_name: str
    isactive: bool


Did you look at computed fields? https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.0/usage/computed_fields/

There are several approaches, the choice of the right one depends on the number of parameters, the need for serialization, etc.
The easiest one would be just to implement the computed field as @MatsLindh mentioned in the comments:
class UserDTO(InternalEntity):
    ...
    company: _CompanyBase

    @computed_field
    @property
    def company_name(self) -> str:
        return self.company.name


user = UserDTO(...)
user.company_name

If your DTOs start to look like logically completely different entities I would recommend splitting them into multiple DTOs:
class UserDTOBase(BaseModel):
    ...


class UserDTOShort(UserDTOBase):
    company_name: str


class UserDTO(UserDTOBase):
    company: _CompanyBase

    def to_short(self) -> UserDTOShort:
        """Convert user DTO to short version."""

        return UserDTOShort(**self.dict(), company_name=self.company.name)


user = UserDTO(...)
user_short = user.to_short()
user.company_name

